# Email Open Tracking: Bypassing an email forwarder that strips the attributes in an image tag?

Tags: html, email, tags, image, tracking

This may be impossible but I figured I'd give it a shot. If the service that I am using strips the attributes of an image tag  => , is there any way that I can get around it?

I tried inserting random unicode characters to break the parser but that failed miserably...

My ultimate goal is to be able to track the email opens and the only way I know how to do that  is through an image in the html of the email...

Thanks!
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to track opens. Like for instance requesting a CSS-file from server, clicking any link, loading a bgsound, or rendering one specific (or any) image. The transparent pixel ist the most common way.

(As I don't see any option to ask for more details besides answering: What service? And what attributes get stripped?)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately gmail doesn't open external css files, loading background sounds. And images are stripped by the service... Thanks!

Comment: That's true. There's no one single perfect way. The webbug works for most. If that's not enough, you got to combine multiple measures.